# Process SSAS Tabular Models using Python

Tags: python, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

I want to execute TMSL scripts to process SSAS tabular models (On-Prem) using Python.

I have my SSAS HTTP endpoint ready.

Any leads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to execute TMSL scripts on SSAS Tabular Model using IronsPython2 and python XMLA package. You can even execute MDX with the above mentioned utility and packages.

Comment: Could you give me more instructions on doing this please @Ankur

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, you cannot execute TMSL scripts to process SSAS tabular models using Python.

The easiest way to explore TMSL scripting is using the CREATE, ALTER, DELETE, or Process commands in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) on a model you already know.

**Reference:** "[Tabular Model Scripting Language(TMSL) reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/bi-reference/tmsl/tabular-model-scripting-language-tmsl-reference)".

Hope this helps.